# Prove $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+d}+\frac{c}{d+a}+\frac{d}{a+b} \ge \frac{1}{2}$ where $a,b,c,d \ge 0$

Tags: inequality

Prove $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+d}+\frac{c}{d+a}+\frac{d}{a+b} \ge \frac{1}{2}$ where $a,b,c,d \ge 0$

**My attempt**:I used two ways but I get to a wrong answer.

**My first way**:We know that $\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{a} \ge 2$ where $a,b \ge 0$

Then:

$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{b}{c+d}+\frac{c+d}{b}+\frac{c}{d+a}+\frac{d+a}{c}+\frac{d}{a+b}+\frac{a+b}{d} \ge 8$

And:

$\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+d}{b}+\frac{d+a}{c}+\frac{a+b}{d}=\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{d}{b}+\frac{d}{c}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{a}{d}+\frac{b}{d}=$

$\frac{a}{c}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b}{d}+\frac{d}{b} \ge 4$

$+$

$\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{d}{c}+\frac{a}{d}\ge 4\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}*\frac{c}{b}*\frac{d}{c}*\frac{a}{d}}=4$

Then:

$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{b}{c+d}+\frac{c+d}{b}+\frac{c}{d+a}+\frac{d+a}{c}+\frac{d}{a+b}+\frac{a+b}{d} \ge 8$

And:

$\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+d}{b}+\frac{d+a}{c}+\frac{a+b}{d}=\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}+\frac{c}{b}+\frac{d}{b}+\frac{d}{c}+\frac{a}{c}+\frac{a}{d}+\frac{b}{d}\ge 8$

Then we will get:

$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+d}+\frac{c}{d+a}+\frac{d}{a+b} \ge 0$

Which is not true.

**My second way**:I don't have enough time then I just explain it.

I used caushy-shuartz and I get:

$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+d}+\frac{c}{d+a}+\frac{d}{a+b} \ge 2$

Comment: I would also think, just from looking at it, that $2$ is the actual lower bound for your expression. In any case, if you've shown that it must be greater than $2$, then you've shown that it must be greater than $\frac12$, haven't you?

Comment: @Arthur Maybe the answer in the book is wrong and the answer is $2$?

Comment: What do you mean, "wrong"? True, $\frac12$ isn't the sharpest bound you can get, and that's unusual for an inequality problem like this, but it's still correct. It's probably a typo, though, and supposed to be $2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab+ac} \ge \frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{ab+bc+cd+da+2ac+2bd}=\frac{(a+b+c+d)^2}{(a+c)(b+d)+2ac+2bd}$$

From Cauchy.

$$(a+b+c+d)^2=(a+c)^2+(b+d)^2+2(a+c)(b+d) \ge 4ac +4bd+2(a+c)(b+d)$$

Since $(x+y)^2 \ge 4xy$.

So $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c} \ge 2 >\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{b+c}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{ab+ac}\geq\frac{(a+b+c+s)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(ab+ac)}\geq2$

Because the last inequality it's $(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2\geq0$. Done!

Comment: The same answer is posted below.

Comment: Not exactly, but Indeed it's similar.

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$P=\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+d}+\frac{c}{d+a}+\frac{d}{a+b}$$

$$Q=\frac{b}{b+c}+\frac{c}{c+d}+\frac{d}{d+a}+\frac{a}{a+b}$$

$$R=\frac{c}{b+c}+\frac{d}{c+d}+\frac{a}{d+a}+\frac{b}{a+b}$$

We have $$Q+R=4\tag{1}$$

$$P+Q=\frac{a+b}{b+c}+\frac{b+c}{c+d}+\frac{c+d}{d+a}+\frac{d+a}{a+b} \overbrace{\geq}^{\color{red}{\text{AM} \geq \text{GM}}} 4\tag{2}$$

$$\begin{align} P+R=\frac{a+c}{b+c}+\frac{b+d}{c+d}+\frac{c+a}{d+a}+\frac{d+b}{a+b}\\ = \left(\frac{a+c}{b+c}+\frac{a+c}{d+a}\right)+ \left(\frac{b+d}{c+d}+\frac{b+d}{a+b}\right) \\
\overbrace{\geq}^{\color{blue}{\text{Titu's Lemma}}} \frac{4(a+c)}{a+b+c+d}+\frac{4(b+d)}{a+b+c+d}=4\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

Using $(1),(2)$ and $(3)$, we get the desired result.